# The best way to prevent having nullable logger

Tags: c#, .net-core, try-catch, error-logging

Let's say we have a simple piece of code:

```
var logger = container.GetInstance<ILogger>();
try {
   //some logic here
}
catch(Exception e){
    logger.Error(e);
}
```

In the case when the logger is *null* I'll get an Exception in the catch block, which is quite obvious.
The quick workaround would be just adding a simple check

```
logger?.Error(e);
```

to prevent having another exception in the catch block.
However, I'm just thinking if I ever should be worried about having a nullable logger in the app or there should be some protection layer, created somewhere which prevents such a behavior?
Cheers

Comment: It's very rare to have a logger which is `null`. Most frameworks will substitute some sort of `NullLogger` - a logger instance which is not null, but does not do anything with your log messages.

Comment: I think in theory, since a logger is potentially used across an entire application, you should try to catch a null logger object before you inject it into any service/class. It might be a symptom of something larger with your dependency injection as well.

Comment: In the project we use SimpleInjector

Comment: If you're worried about having a nullable logger then your code is fine, because it will throw an exception if it's nullable, so it won't go unnoticed unless you're swallowing the error.